# Create a form select list in Ember 2.2

Tags: ember.js

Hi I'm trying to create a select list as part of a login form. The form submits and passes the two input text values but doesn't see the select list.

```
<form id="form-login" {{action 'authenticate' on='submit'}}>
    <fieldset>
        {{input id='identification' value=identification placeholder='Username'}}
        {{input id='password' value=password placeholder='Password' type='password'}}

        <select id="language" name="language">
            <option value="ENG">English</option>
            <option value="">Not English</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

    {{#if errorMessage}}
    <div>
        <strong>Login failed:</strong> {{errorMessage}}
    </div>
    {{/if}}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
</form>
```

I tried these steps but it says they're deprecated and don't work? http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html

```
{{view "select" content=languages value=selectedLanguage}}
```

That's the only page on their documentation I could find?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected value needs to be set on the context. Right now the value isn't being set at all.

**controller**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  language: 'English',
  languages: ['English', 'Non English'],
  actions: {
    authenticate() {
      // Set values from form and submit to server...
    }
  }
});
```

**template**

```
<form id="form-login" {{action 'authenticate' on='submit'}}>
  <fieldset>
    {{input id='identification' value=identification placeholder='Username'}}
    {{input id='password' value=password placeholder='Password' type='password'}}

    <select onchange={{action (mut language) value="target.value"}} id="language" name="language">
      {{#each languages as |languageChoice|}}
        <option value={{languageChoice}} selected={{eq language languageChoice}}>{{languageChoice}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
  </fieldset>

  {{#if errorMessage}}
    <div>
      <strong>Login failed:</strong> {{errorMessage}}
    </div>
  {{/if}}

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
</form>
```

Here's [a post with a good explanation](http://balinterdi.com/2015/08/29/how-to-do-a-select-dropdown-in-ember-20.html) of everything that's going on.

Comment: This link inside your link is exactly what I needed thanks! https://github.com/balinterdi/replace-ember-select-view-with-event-listeners/tree/eaa8272304a72d19e1941e8cc9f113ee9534943f